# Display latest post of taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have custom post type (entertainment) and I set up a taxonomy (review) as hierarchal so there are check boxes under the taxonomy. Most of the post in the entertainment are just post but we also have reviews. What I was hoping is that if it's a review then you can just check what type of review in the review taxonomy box, an example is "movie". I am trying to display the latest review using

```
query_posts( array('tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'review','field' => 'slug','term' => 'movie')), 'posts_per_page'=>'1', 'caller_get_posts'=>'1') );
```

But it's showing the latest post and not the one selected as movie.

I'm on WP 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a straight query for the taxonomy term:

```
query_posts( array( 'review' => 'movie' ) );
```

To query multiple terms you can use tax_query:

```
'tax_query' =>     array(
            'taxonomy' => 'review',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'movie', 'term', 'term' ),
        ),
```

Comment: that worked, I'm always trying to do it more complicated than it should be. Now what if I wanted to check multiple terms? I tried `'review'=>array('term,'term,'term')` and that didn't work.

Comment: @kel see updated answer

Comment: the second one didn't work for me.

Comment: I got it now it should be `'tax_query' =>     array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'review',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'movie', 'term', 'term' ))
        ),`